# Getting '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number when working with minio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, minio

I installed local minio storage:

```
wget https://dl.min.io/server/minio/release/linux-amd64/minio
chmod +x minio
./minio server /home/myuser/minio_storage --console-address ":5050"
```

I'm trying to connect and create new bucket:

```
    client = Minio("127.0.0.1:5050")        
    found = client.bucket_exists("my_bucket")
    if not found:
        client.make_bucket("my_bucket")
    else:
        print("Bucket 'my_bucket' already exists")
```

And I'm getting error:

```
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5050): Max retries exceeded with url: /my_buket (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:852)'
```

What do I need to do in order to create new bucket ?

Answer (score 11):

You've started the minio service without TLS enabled and so the service is running on the HTTP protocol on port `5050`.

You therefore need to tell the client to connect using HTTP also by using the `secure=False` option as [documented](https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-api-reference.html)

```py
client = Minio("127.0.0.1:5050", secure=False)
```

Or configure the server to be running with TLS which is the better option which is also [documented](https://docs.min.io/docs/how-to-secure-access-to-minio-server-with-tls.html).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and adding `secure=False` to the constructor of the minio client fixed it for me.